# Structural integrity of enclosed porch - 1950s home with porch enclosed in late 70s

Tags: framing, structural

This is regarding a 1950s home with the porch having been enclosed in the late 70s. Located in New York.

It seems they used 2x3s to frame it and they put the new roof over the existing roof (didn't remove the original roof). This was permitted and approved by the building department at the time.

I've only seen 2x3s used for closets and small rooms. I was also very surprised to see the original roof (including gutters!) still intact under the new roof.

Is this good practice for today's standards?

Thanks for your thoughts! See photos below.

[image: New roof on top of original roof]

[image: Full room]

[image: View of left side]

[image: View looking toward house of new roof over original roof]

[image: View looking toward house showing where original roof ends]

Comment: 50 plus years.  Are there any signs of sagging, drywall mud cracking, bowing of studs?  Are you going to add extra weight, besides more insulation?